# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for "ONLY" case.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There was 50 students to choose among three courses Maths, Science and Arts. Here is the information given.

30 choose Arts.

12 choose Science.

10 choose both Arts and Science.

8 choose Arts and Mathematics.

6 choose Arts, Science and Mathematics.

14 choose none of them.

Also, the number of students who choose Mathematics is three times the students who choose Mathematics and Science.

The question is, what is the total number of students who choose Maths only, Science only and Arts only ?

I am okay if I do it using Venn diagram. But how to do it by using inclusion-exclusion principle ?

Comment: Neither of them is ambigious.

Comment: what do you mean. Neither of them here means the student did not take any courses listed.

Comment: Arts only equals Arts minus (Arts and Science) minus (Arts and Math) plus (Arts and Science and Math).

Comment: @GerryMyerson , you get this one using Venn diagram or by using inclusion exclusion principle ? I did get this one too but I wonder this formula came from where.

Comment: I think of it as one way of writing inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: We have the inclusion-exclusion principle formula given by $|U|=|S|+|M|-|S\cap M|+|S'\cap M'|$. Can I conclude your above statement by looking that $A$ to be universal set and hence we have $|A|=|A\cap S|+|A\cap M| - |A\cap S\cap M|+|A\cap S'\cap M'|$?

@GerryMyerson

Comment: @LingMinHao.  Neither means not one and not the other.  Neither of them (those two) does not mean none of them (three or more)..

Comment: Okay. Then it should be none of them.

Comment: Yes, Ling, that looks right.

Comment: There does not seem to be an answer in non-negative integers. If "three times" were changed to "double", there would be.

Comment: Sorry the three times should be arts and mathematics

Comment: @LingMinHao: you might update the question with the corrections you've noted in comments.